# Manually created groups are not listed in uaa jwt token

Tags: jwt, cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-uaa

After decoding the UAA jwt token, I can see some groups in scope which are already present in UAA's yml file. But i can not see the groups which are created manually.

Is it possible to get the groups which are created by me from jwt token?

Answer (score 1):

Please check with whether groups and scope are same where it is linked? thanks for your understanding